# Error al poner una imágen de fondo mediante SCSS

Tags: html, css, scss

Estoy intentando poner una imagen de fondo para el layout de un nav, pero al pasarle la imagen mediante la propiedad "background-image" no me aparece la misma y  salta el siguiente error en consola:

```
GET http://127.0.0.1:5500/IMG/casita-en-mar-del- 
sur.jpg 404 (Not Found)
```

Obviamente me está diciendo que no encuentra la imagen, pero no entiendo el por qué si la ruta que especifico es la correcta.

HTML:

```
<header class="header">
    <div class="contenedor contenido-principal">

    </div>
</header>
```

SCSS:

```
.contenido-principal {

background-image: url(../../IMG/casita-en-mar-del- 
sur.jpg);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
width: 100%;
height: 10rem;

}
```

Comment: No será que la URL del `background-image` está recortada con un salto de línea?... prueba que esté todo en 1 línea... ya que eso sería lo mismo que `../../IMG/casita-en-mar-del-  sur.jpg`

Comment: Hola! Gracias por sus respuestas. Ahí me fije pero el saltó de línea lo puse por acá solamente, en el código original no estaba. Igual probé borrando y reescribiendo la URL varias veces corroborando que no haya ningún salto de línea ni nada pero sigue ocurriendo lo mismo. Es más, cuando intento poner la misma ruta pero a través de HTML si me toma la imágen JPG. (No así con .avif o .webp, otro problema al cuál le estoy buscando solución).

Answer (score 0):

Tal y como se indica en el error 404, la ruta de la propiedad `background-image` está llevando a una imagen que no existe en el enlace. Lo más probable es que esté fallando porque hay un salto de línea entre del- y sur.jpg.